# MongoDB: attempt to explain query fails on sort memory limit

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the 'Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM' error on some query. However what is even more troublesome, is that I can't even run it with `.explain()`:

```
> db.collection.find({...}, {...}).limit(5000).sort({...})
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.\"",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
}

> db.collection.find({...}, {...}).limit(5000).sort({...}).explain()
2019-07-22T09:15:38.246+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: explain failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.\"",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
throwOrReturn@src/mongo/shell/explainable.js:31:1
constructor/this.finish@src/mongo/shell/explain_query.js:172:24
DBQuery.prototype.explain@src/mongo/shell/query.js:521:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Tried to recreate the index but nothing changed.

What could be happening here?

**Edit:** To clarify, the sort field is indexed and in the correct sort order. I was wondering why the explain fails, which seemed odd to me and I thought there might be data corruption going on here. How are we meant to diagnose a problematic query with explain if it fails on what we are trying to diagnose?

**Edit 2:** Upon further diagnosis I could literally pinpoint it to `.limit(4308)` works and `.limit(4309)` barfs. However there is nothing wrong with the 4309th record...

Furthermore this happens in one env and not the other that are identical expect for data.

Comment: 1. Too many docs returned from find filter to sort in memory
2. Unused/wrong Index created

Comment: I should have clarified that I understand the error and that an index on the sort field exists. I just don't understand how explain could fail...

Comment: It makes sense that the server first executes and then explains it to you, if there is an error executing the query, what exactly will it explain?

Comment: @Ashh allowDiskUse is for aggregation. Amir, reduce the limit. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions

Comment: @AmirAbiri I am damn sure You have not indexed the correct field.

Comment: The sort field is indexed.

Comment: @RakshithSm It's not that the query is unparsable. If the limit is reduced it works. However in order to diagnose where the performance problem is, one would add `.explain()`. At this point you wouldn't expect the query to fail since it shouldn't actually perform the query, just show the query plan.

Answer (score 2):

For any time travelers from the future:

RE `.explain()`, seems to be just a quirk in Mongo. To see the query plan the limit must be reduced. I guess as silly as this sounds Mongo **actually runs the query** and then shows the query plan...

Worth noting that this is Mongo 3.4. Might have changed by now...

Our performance problem came down to having a huge subobject property (let's call it `.metaData`). However since we know it's problematic we didn't include it in the projection. But - it does appear in the find criteria as `{metaData: {$exists: true}}`. I guess mongo fetches the whole thing and keeps it in memory only to do `{$exists: true}` on it. That led the query to blow up the 32M memory limit eventhough the actual result requires much less memory and the sort field is indexed.

So we live to write more bugs another day...

Comment: Kind of what I wanted to tell, But I guess I did a bad job at it!
>actually runs the query - It does, that what I wanted to say

Comment: Mongo indeed "fetches the whole thing": https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15200, but it doesn't explain why in-memory sort triggered at the first place since it uses correct indexes. It would be interesting to see a reproducible example if you have  a chance to create one.

Comment: The "Sort operation used..." error message will only show up if it actually is doing an in-memory sort. Maybe the query planner decided to use a different index than you intended, or maybe the index doesn't entirely work for the sort that they're doing -- it's impossible to tell without looking at an explain. (Limiting to N is the normal way to get access to the explain when this happens -- it won't change the query plan, only the number of documents it's doing the plan on)

Comment: It's possible that I misread the query plan. Perhaps doing `{metaData: {$exists: true}}` confused the query planner enough to not use the index on the sort field. By simply doing `{'metaData.timestamp': {$exists: true}}` instead - **which is the sort field** - the problem went away.